# Using temporary layer in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: c#, add-in, arcgis-pro-sdk

I use C# for creating an AddIn for ArcGIS Pro 3.1. One of the features of the AddIn is to jump to a position.

```
var wgs84 = SpatialReferences.WGS84;
var pointInWGS84 = MapPointBuilder.CreateMapPoint(Convert.ToDouble(result.lon), Convert.ToDouble(result.lat), wgs84);

var currentSystem = MapView.Active.Camera.SpatialReference;

MapPoint pointInCurrentSystem = (MapPoint)GeometryEngine.Instance.Project(pointInWGS84, currentSystem);

const int DefaultScaleAfterZoom = 5000;
var camera = new Camera(pointInCurrentSystem.X, pointInCurrentSystem.Y, DefaultScaleAfterZoom, MapView.Active.Camera.Heading);

MapView.Active.ZoomToAsync(camera, TimeSpan.Zero);
```

Now I want to set a temporary marker on that position. Is there some kind of "temporary" layer, which is made for temporary marking things or do I have to use a regular layer?

I want to avoid, that this marker has any effect on the layer list or something else the user can configure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that would be possible by calling one of the [`AddOverlay()`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/sdk/api-reference/topic27596.html) overloads on the mapview. The graphic will be visible until you dispose it.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @Berend's answer, I found this example in the offical documentation: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/sdk/api-reference/topic27596.html

So I finally used this code to draw a temporary circle at a specific map point:

```
    private async void DrawMarker(MapPoint pointInCurrentSystem)
    {
        var mapView = MapView.Active;
        if (mapView == null)
            return;

        m_marker = await QueuedTask.Run(() =>
        {
            return mapView.AddOverlay(pointInCurrentSystem,
                SymbolFactory.Instance.ConstructPointSymbol(
                        ColorFactory.Instance.GreyRGB, 20.0, SimpleMarkerStyle.Circle).MakeSymbolReference());
        });

    }
```